# Change position GPS and TextView when phone is lock

Tags: android, gps, textview

I want to create app which will add new longitude and latitude every 3 second to the textview in scrollview. I have a problem with adding new coordinates when the phone is locked or app work in background

```
public class PomiarTrasy extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomiar_trasy);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        txt1.setText("Szukanie pozycji...");

    } else {
        txt1.setText("Twój GPS jest wyłączony");

    }

    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        txt1.setText("Szukanie pozycji...");

    else
        txt1.setText("Twój GPS jest wyłączony");
}

LocationManager lm;
Location savedLocation = null;
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";

        if (location != null) {

            latitude += location.getLatitude();
            longitude += location.getLongitude();
            txt1.setText("Uzyskano współrzędne!");
        }

        btn_start_zapis.setEnabled(true);

        if (wlacz == 1) {

            txt4.setText(txt4.getText() + "" + location.getLongitude() + ", " + location.getLatitude() + "\n");
            txt5.setText(txt2.getText());
            txt6.setText(txt3.getText());
            txt2.setText(latitude);
            txt3.setText(longitude);
    }

        if (savedLocation == null) {
            savedLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        txt1.setText("Szukanie pozycji...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        txt1.setText("Twój GPS jest wyłączony");
    }
};
```

Any sugestion how I can do it? I read about the `Service` - GPS work in background, but how do it with `TextView`?

Comment: Separate the actions of (1) getting the latest coordinates, and (2) putting the latest coordinates on the TextView. (1) can happen in your service, periodically. (2) should happen whenever the app (re)gains focus, and periodically.

Comment: While I hope my comment will point you in the right direction, this question is too broad to be answered effectively on the [so] platform. Good luck!

Comment: So I should create activity Service.class and this service only get the coordinates (and in this class should be onLocationChanged, onProviderEnabled etc.?) . And actions of putting text should be in new Service class or in MainActivity? Cause I try create Service.class and I see what GPS work in background but still doesn't work putting text in TextView. I will be very grateful if you explain this problem.

Comment: You don't need to put text into the TextView until it is visible to the user again. You just have to hook into the right UI events to ensure you're always loading the new value as soon as the TextView becomes visible again.

Comment: But if I need add every new coordinates to TextView when the phone is lock? This is problem for me. I need get every new signal and put it into TextView, and it will be using in next step of app

Comment: If you need to add more than one coordinate, then store them in a list. You don't have to update the UI every time you update the data structure. You *should* update the data structure whenever you get a new value; however, you should not update the UI until it makes sense to do so from the end-user's perspective.

Comment: To rephrase my first comment, separate the rendering of the values (TextView) from the storing of the values. Store them somewhere else, and copy them to the TextView when it makes sense to do so. Then, TextView is not the master copy; it's only the user's window into your world. Sometimes, the window is closed (the user cannot see), but the world should still exist, independently of the window (TextView) itself, and operates the same way (the coordinates continue to refresh or accumulate).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I try do it with your tips :)